# How to autoincrease PO number , and link it to my main table?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I am facing this issue for a couple of weeks and i am using MS Access.

**My issue is that I would like to have My PO number auto increase**, however the PO number is not my primary key, instead ID is my primary key. I used ID as my primary because under one PO, it will have more than one fabrication.

I construct my running number table as below: 
ID Autonumber 
PO Number Shorttext

After setting up the PO number, i would like to link it to my main table so that i will be able to search the PO number and all the data that are store under the PO number that i am searching will show on on my subform. I would also like that the PO number will not increase until i have click on the "add" button on my form. 
How can i do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a little more info about the fields in your Main table, the fields in your PO table, and how they relate to each other.  What you're talking about is a job for VBA, but how the PO numbers relate to records in the main table affect how it is done.  Sometimes po numbers follow a format like 987-001, 987-002, 987-003, etc where '987' refers to the client or the project or something like that and "-001", "-002" and "-003" refer to the PO's for those entities.  What's your methodology?

Comment: Review http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=23329

Comment: @jcropp thank you for replying! My table structure for the PO number is: ID Autonumber  PO number Short text. My table structure for main table to link them together will be through ID as i used ID as my PK. Po number looks like this: ABC17/001  ABC represent the company, 17/ represent the year which is 2017, 001 represent the number that i want it to be increase after i click on "Add" on form.

Comment: Review : Cross posted here: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=295412